# JPA perfomance with case insensitive in select

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a JPA select where you receibe a parameter then we can search using some attributes (username, email, identifier) The user only have a text field to write the criteria text.

The problem is perfomance, in the database We have about 9Millions of users registereds, and the search is too slow, using JPA,

> Form:
>   - Value (Input text)

User sends the value in the form (He doesn't say if he is using username, email or identifier)

> User (Table) Fields:
>   - Identifier
>   - Name
>   - Email

**JPA Query**:

```
select u from UserEntity u where u.alias LIKE lower(:query) OR u.email LIKE lower(:query) OR lower(u.identifier) LIKE lower(:query) ORDER BY u.alias
```

I don't know what the best method to improve the speed of the search, (We have some indexes in the table in these fields), if we remove the lower in the u.identifier field the speed improves a lot (almost instant). But we can have the identifier in a lot of ways (migrations, registers, manual client inserts..)

Comment: "Using JPA", and a JPA provider will simply convert it to SQL and runs that. So why not look at the generated SQL and concentrate on that?

Answer (score 1):

> We have about 9 Millions of users registered, and the search is too slow, using JPA

Please note the search will be too slow regardless the technology involved in executing the query just because the SQL query itself is too slow. That being said the problem is not JPA but how to improve the SQL query.

Combining LOWER() function with LIKE operator adds a lot of overhead because the RDBMS must apply a text function to 3 fields before analyse the LIKE match.

IMHO a good approach is using a VIEW to leverage the LOWER() part on the 3 fields and then execute the query over this view (BTW mapping a View with JPA is just as simple as mapping a Table):

```
CRAETE VIEW user_view AS SELECT id, lower(identifier) AS identifier, lower(alias) AS alias, lower(email) AS email FROM user;
```

Then create an entity for searching:

```
@Entity
@Table("user_view")
public class UserView {

    @Basic private Long id;
    @Basic private String identifier;
    @Basic private String alias;
    @Basic private String email;

    // getters and setters as required
}
```

And finally the JPQL query:

```
String jqpl = "SELECT u FROM UserView u WHERE u.alias LIKE :query OR u.email LIKE :query OR u.identifier LIKE :query";
```

Note that you can pass `query` parameter directly in lower case as a Query parameter and you can order the result list after the query execution. Both will result in the RDBMS making less effort and consequently improving the overall response time.

Comment: The view encapsulates the query, but I don't see how it will improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using different techniques.

One is using a collate that ignores case. For example in MySQL https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html

Another strategy is to have a derived field with an index. In DB2, for example, you can create a field 'lower_identifier generated always as lower(identifier)' and an index in the field and it will use it automatically when doing a lower search. You don't have to map the field in JPA.